# How do I make changes to the "Data Safety" section in the whole GooglePlay account?

Tags: google-play-console

I have a problem with the "Data Safety" section.
There are about 200 apps in my GooglePlay developer account.
In all applications, the "Data Safety" section was initially filled out incorrectly, I did not take into account the "AdMob" advertising factor, which collects user data.
Now I want to correct the situation and change the status in the "Data Safety" section. However, I have concerns that with such large-scale changes, not only those applications where I have already fixed everything, but also those where I have not yet managed to make corrections at the time of the start of the review, will inevitably fall under the test. As a result, I will receive a lot of criticism and the account will be banned. Can someone suggest a way out?
Does it make sense to disable applications for a while - transfer them to the "Unpublish" status, make changes to the "Data Safety" and "Adversity ID" sections, and then submit them for verification in small batches?

Answer (score 0):

First of all having 200 apps on one account is very risky with Google play, you may got banned just because you have that many apps.

You can export a data safety form from an correct app using `Export to CSV` then `Import from CSV` to other apps. this is much much quicker than filling all safety report by yourself.

I do not recommend unpublishing your apps, because the Admob ads will be restricted.

[image]